# Dask - concatenate two same-column dataframes doesn't work

Tags: pandas, dask

I have two dataframes without a header line, both with the same comma-separated columns.
I tried to read them into one dataframe with

```
dfoutputs = dd.read_csv(['outputsfile.csv', 'outputsfile2.csv'], names=colnames, header=None, dtype={'firstnr': 'Int64', 'secondnr': 'Int64', 'thirdnr': 'Int64', 'fourthnr': 'Int64'})
```

but this dataframe only contained `outputsfile.csv` rows.

Similar problem for reading and concat:

```
colnames=['firstnr', 'secondnr', 'thirdnr', 'fourthnr'] 
dfoutputs = dd.read_csv('outputsfile.csv', names=colnames, header=None, dtype={'firstnr': 'Int64', 'secondnr': 'Int64', 'thirdnr': 'Int64', 'fourthnr': 'Int64'})
print(dfoutputs.head(10))

dfoutputs2 = dd.read_csv('outputsfile2.csv', names=colnames, header=None, dtype={'firstnr': 'Int64', 'secondnr': 'Int64', 'thirdnr': 'Int64', 'fourthnr': 'Int64'})
print(dfoutputs2.head(10))

dfnew  = dd.concat([dfoutputs, dfoutputs2])
print(dfnew.head(10))
```

Output:

```
   firstnr  secondnr  thirdnr      fourthnr
0  0        0     0      5000000000
1  1        0     0      5000000000
2  2        0     0      5000000000
3  3        0     0      5000000000
4  4        0     0      5000000000
5  5        0     0      5000000000

   firstnr  secondnr  thirdnr      fourthnr
0  11       0     0      5000000000
1  12       0     0      5000000000

   firstnr  secondnr  thirdnr      fourthnr
0  0        0     0      5000000000
1  1        0     0      5000000000
2  2        0     0      5000000000
3  3        0     0      5000000000
4  4        0     0      5000000000
5  5        0     0      5000000000
```

How can I combine both csv's to the same Dask dataframe?

Comment: I think you should use append instead. It's much more straight forward. Open the other file as a text file, readline and append.

Comment: That would be similar to a `pd.concat([dfoutputs, dfoutputs2])`

Comment: Yes, it would. The only difference is that you won't be creating another data frame, much better space utilisation and a neat code.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to read the same file twice in the first code snippet.

Comment: @BrianLarsen Thanks, but that was a typo here. Same problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by TennisTechBoy in the comments:

```
f=open("outputsfile.csv", "a")

f2=open("outputsfile2.csv", "r")
f2content = f2.readlines()
for i in range(len(f2content)):
    f.write(f2content[i])
f.close()
f2.close()
```

A way to do this in Dask might be needed from a memory perspective.